# How to create a list of accounts -> passwords and share it for Postfix and Dovecot?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, imap, dovecot

This is my Postfix configuration:

```
root@vmi2198:/etc/postfix# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = /etc/postfix/mydestination
mydomain = example.net
myhostname = mail.example.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/postfix/mail
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

I have set the PATH to store the messages and create the maps, like:

```
info@example.com example.com/info/
```

Now I would protect my accounts with the password (SASL) How can I create a list of account -> password and share this list for postfix and Dovecot ?

Answer (score 1):

This is described in the Dovecot documentation:
http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL

and in the Postfix documentation:
http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_dovecot